# Como puedo crear varios controles Image en un Grid a los cuales les pueda agregar las imágenes de una carpeta la cual puede ir cambiando contenido

Tags: c#, wpf

Tengo una carpeta llamada Images y dentro otra llamada IOS y lo que quiero es que cuando el usuario pulse un botón el Grid agregue columnas y filas y a esa celda agregarle un control Image. Esto con todas las imágenes que contenga la carpeta (en este caso 70 y en futuro mas o menos).

[image: este es el diseño]

```
private void BTN_IOS_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string path = @"..\..\Images\IOS";
        System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(path);
        System.IO.FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
        RTXT_Message.Document.Blocks.Clear();
        Lines.Inlines.Clear();
        Lines.Inlines.Add(files.Count().ToString() + " Imagenes encontradas"); ;
        FlowDoc_Messages.Blocks.Add(Lines);
        RTXT_Message.Document = FlowDoc_Messages;
        foreach (System.IO.FileInfo img in files)
        {
            BitmapImage bmpi = new BitmapImage();
            bmpi.BeginInit();
            bmpi.UriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/IOS", UriKind.Absolute);
            bmpi.EndInit();

            ImageBrush imgb = new ImageBrush();
            imgb.ImageSource = bmpi;
            Image imgC = new Image();
            imgC.Source = bmpi;

            G_Selection.Children.Add(imgC);

            //for (int i = 0; i <= files.Count(); i++)
            //{
            //    ColumnDefinition Col = new ColumnDefinition();
            //    G_Selection.ColumnDefinitions.Add(Col);
            //    RowDefinition Row1 = new RowDefinition();
            //    G_Selection.RowDefinitions.Add(Row1);
            //    Image image = new Image();
            //    BitmapImage bmpImage = new BitmapImage();
            //    bmpImage.BeginInit();
            //    bmpImage.UriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/IOS/001-mail inbox app.png");
            //    bmpImage.EndInit();
            //    image.Source = bmpImage;

            //    ImageBrush imgBrs = new ImageBrush();
            //    imgBrs.ImageSource = bmpImage;
            //    IMG_IOS1.Source = bmpImage;
            //}
        }
    }
```

y ese el código que tengo, el cual solo me pone la imagen si le especifico el nombre de ella, pero no me crea las filas ni las columnas y tampoco el Image, solo cambia la imagen del control actual (el que tiene la tuerca).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no sea si sea la mejor manera pero creo que lo he resuelto. lo que hice fue tomar el objeto "files" que es un arreglo de tipo system.IO.FileInfo y hacer un foreach con este. luego añadiendo el nombre del archivo final con files[pos] donde pos es una variable que aumenta en cada pasada del foreach:

```
 string path = @"..\..\Images\IOS";
        System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(path);
        System.IO.FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
        RTXT_Message.Document.Blocks.Clear();
        Lines.Inlines.Clear();
        Lines.Inlines.Add(files.Count().ToString() + " Imagenes encontradas"); ;
        FlowDoc_Messages.Blocks.Add(Lines);
        RTXT_Message.Document = FlowDoc_Messages;
        int pos = 0;
        int pos2 = 0;
        foreach (System.IO.FileSystemInfo item in files)
        {
            string name = files[pos].ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(name);
            BitmapImage bmpi = new BitmapImage();
            bmpi.BeginInit();
            bmpi.UriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/IOS/" + name, UriKind.Absolute);
            bmpi.EndInit();
            Image imgC = new Image();
            imgC.Source = bmpi;
            imgC.Width = 100;
            imgC.Height = 100;
            imgC.RenderSize = new Size(100, 100);
            pos++;
            if (this.WindowState == WindowState.Normal)
            {

                if (pos <= 4)
                {
                    PNL_Selection.Children.Add(imgC);
                }
                else
                {
                    StackPanel stpnl = new StackPanel();
                    stpnl.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
                    stpnl.Width = PNL_Selection.Width;
                    stpnl.Height = PNL_Selection.Height;
                    stpnl.Margin = PNL_Selection.Margin;
                    G_AuxGrid.Children.Add(stpnl);
                    stpnl.Children.Add(imgC);
                }
            }
        }
```

Ahora solo falta resolver un problema, y es que al añadir la imagen en un Stack panel que he agregado por código este no distribuye la imagen horizontalmente si no que coloca imagen sobre imagen.

Comment: Para que distribuya las imágenes intenta darle un tamaño determinado, por ejemplo 100x100 y entonces el stackpanel va a colocar las imágenes una al lado de la otra de forma automática apilando hacia abajo cuando el espacio horizontal se llene... sino siempre va a ocupar el total disponible

Comment: he intentado darle una tamaño predeterminado de 495*516 pero no da, lo que hace ahora es poner las imagenes en horizontal pero parece que es infinito por que todas van horizontal, asi que solo se pueden ver una 10 imagenes y las demas desaparecen